# Sending a message to update the tab's URL based on a URL and variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm searching through pages on a site for specific keywords. When the keywords are found, they currently print to the console.

If they are not found, I want the URL to go to the next page on the current tab to continue to look.

The URL looks like so: https://example.com/?page= and ideally, will update the tab URL to the next page number (?page=1 for example, to ?page=2) when no matches are found.

This is my sendMessage in content_script.js

```
if(match !== true){
    console.log("No Matches.")

    num = ++num;

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(num, function(response) {
        console.log(`message sent`);
      });
    
}
```

The match variable seems to be working correctly, and num is updating. In the background.js I have the following:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(num => {
    var url = "https://example.com/?page=";
    url = url + num;

    console.log("URL is now: " + url);
    
    chrome.tabs.update(url);
    
    return true; 
});
```

I tried an append and set but couldn't get it to work correctly either.

I keep receiving the following:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

If I remove my attempt to change the URL (url = url + num, etc.) and just hardcode a URL, it works as expected when no content is found (the URL that is hardcoded is loaded). Something like the following works:

```
chrome.tabs.update(https://example.com/?page=50);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using `return true`, which instructs Chrome to wait for a response from the tab using the `sendResponse` parameter/callback, however you're not calling that in your content script.

This means that for every message it receives, it keeps waiting for another response, which never gets, so it just errors out when the port closes (i.e. when the tab closes)

**Remove `return true` if you're not using that feature.**

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage